# Asking how to make my hp regen to regen to full hp and while detecting if there is any sudden healing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Code down here. when i run this in unity when i lose 10 hp (maxhp 100) i regen to maxhp but the problem is i made a hp potion script that heals me 5 hp per drink but when i lose damage example i lose 10 damage and i use my potion making it heals 5 hp = to 95 currenthp the regen still heals 10 hp not 5 going through the 100/maxhp) hp limit. so in conclusion how to tell the part of the code that regens me (ill make it bold so easier to see) to ajust if there is any sudden hp healing

```
**IEnumerator Regeneration()
{
    

        if (currentHealth < maxHealth)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
            Debug.Log("Regen");
            currentHealth += Regen;
        }**
      
    
       
    
}


void takedamage(int damage)
{

    if(Frame == true)
    {
        damage -= armor.getValue();
        Mathf.Clamp(damage, 0, int.MaxValue);
        currentHealth -= damage;
        Frame = false;

      
        StartCoroutine(Regeneration());
   
        Debug.Log(transform.name + " takes " + damage + " damage ");
      
    }
    
       


    if (currentHealth <= 0)
    {
        die();
        Debug.Log(transform.name+" Need to be revive ");
    }
}
void HpRegeneration()
{
    if (currentHealth < maxHealth)
    {
        Debug.Log("Regen");
      
        Mathf.Clamp(Regen, 0, maxHealth);
        currentHealth += Regen;
    }
    if (currentHealth == maxHealth)
    {
       
        Debug.Log("FullHp");
        StopCoroutine(Regeneration());
        
    }
   
}
void die()
{
    Debug.Log(transform.name + "Died");
   
}
```

}

Comment: Check and see if after regen tick its > than max health and if it is set to max health and stop regen?

Answer (score 0):

Your Regeneration enumerator is waiting 5 seconds *after* you perform your health check. A lot can happen in 5 seconds. You need to check for the max health just before you add the recovered health. Why not call your `HpRegeneration()` function? It already has the clamp on the assignment.

```
IEnumerator Regeneration()
{
    

        if (currentHealth < maxHealth)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
            Debug.Log("Regen");
            HpRegeneration();
        }  
}
```

Comment: Hey so there is still something wrong i did the thing in ur reply removing and changed it but the problem is still there i used a debug. log so i can see if it happens still happens even if the hp is full example(lose 10 damage = 90 hp, drink hp potion = 95, hp regen = 105 
like i think the Regeneration script only consider the lost hp lost on the damage and its absolute if u got healed for lets say u have 80 hp and u got heal 50 so ur hp is ofc 100 but the regen still goes over and heals u to 120 the hp that u lost while damaged This will be a problem if i want to make a death effect/anim